# Unable to get $http.post request data in Node.js res.body

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, http-post

I am using Angular 1.3 and node.js 0.12.2 for a project. I am hitting the node.js api using

```
$http.post("url", request_data){}
```

And on server side using this:

```
console.log(req.body)
```

But everytime the api gets called, it gets empty object `{}` for `request_data` , Unable to get what the problem is. I have used `body_parser` like this:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies
```

Have also tried adding content-type header in angular $http as:

```
headers : {'Content-Type': 'applicatio n/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
```

But not getting request data.

**EDIT:**

Node.js code :

```
router.post('/url',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body)  
})
```

Note: Developer Tool's network tab showing the data, I am sending, in request header correctly, but node.js server not receiving in `req.body`.
In POSTman getting data is correctly in response.

Comment: can you share one line nodejs code

Comment: req.body or res.body

Comment: $http.post('url',{data:'data'}, function(res){console.log(res)})

Comment: Try using postman or rest client to test your api

Comment: @JayantPatil -$http.post is Angular's method for sending data to node api. While `console.log(res.body)` is used at node.js server for getting request data @server side. I have tested it in postman, and it is showing my custom error, that no request data recieved, even though "Developer tool"'s network pan showing data in request header.

Comment: Postman showing correct data response

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-do-you-extract-post-data-in-node-js and this http://blog.frankgrimm.net/2010/11/howto-access-http-message-body-post-data-in-node-js/

Comment: I faced the same issue while updating the the document in mongodb. I fixed the problem by adding header `content type` as `application/json`.

Comment: Have you looked in the network tab of the debugger when you make the call?

Comment: @PeteMcKinney yes I have checked it, see the "Note" on last line.

Answer (score 1):

some ideas :

- Maybe an URL error ? Make sure you aren't using a prefix like `app.use('/api', router);`
- Look at the `Content-Type` :

**application/x-www-form-urlencoded** --> `'var1="SomeValue"&var2='+SomeVariable`
**application/json;charset=UTF-8**        --> `{var1:"SomeValue", var2:SomeVariable}`

- You could use `$http` more explicitly :

```html
$http({
  url: '...',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  data: 'var1="SomeValue"&var2='+SomeVariable
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that your angular $http request URL is pointing to a bad end-point.

**Angularjs**

```
// data to post nodejs server
var _data = {
    'message': 'Can I help you?'
};


// angularjs $http post request
$http.post('/api/url', _data).then(function(respond){
    // if success
    console.log(respond);
}, function(error){
    // if an error
    console.error(error);
});
```

**Nodejs**

```
// router function
function something(req, res) {

    // console.log the request body
    console.log(req.body);

    // respond JSON object
    var _respond = {
        'status': 200
    };

    // expressjs respond a JSON with status code 200
    res.status(200).json(_respond);
}

// register route URL
router.post('/api/url', something);
```

Note that the code end point URLs are same : **/api/url**

**Therefore as your code sample in above question, you'r missing a /**

Comment: No, end point is correct, I used dummy url to explain the problem, Node.js is able to get the request. I am using $.ajax, instead of $http. Still there is problem with the data format. So we changed the node.js code. to handle the requested data.

Comment: After using $.ajax, node.js got the header data, but it was not showing the empty array.